# UICollectionView Frame Change

Tags: ios, iphone, uicollectionview

None of the answers I've seen on SO seems to answer this problem. I'm trying to change the frame of a `UICollectionView`. The frame change is shown when logged but it doesn't physically change the frame. I dont have any constraints set on it. Just changing the frame. That's all. I'm creating a non-scrollable `UICollectionView`.

```
    _testStringOne = @"Test String";
    _tagOne = [_testStringOne boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(242.0f, 900.0f) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15.0f]} context:nil];

    _testStringTwo = @"Another Test String";
    _tagTwo = [_testStringTwo boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(242.0f, 900.0f) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15.0f]} context:nil];

    CGRect collectionFrame = self.collectionView.frame;
    if (_tagOne.origin.x + _tagOne.size.width + _tagTwo.origin.x + _tagTwo.size.width > 242.0f)
    {
        collectionFrame.size.height = 62.0f;
        sectionCount = 2;
        itemCount = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        collectionFrame.size.height = 31.0f;
        sectionCount = 1;
        itemCount = 2;
    }
    self.collectionView.frame = collectionFrame;
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
```

Comment: did you create it with IB or by code? If by IB - did you set the autosize and autoalignment?

Comment: Created using IB. I dont have any constraints. Not sure about autosize and auto alignment. When can I check that?

Comment: "dont have any constraints" Do you mean Auto Layout is disabled or you haven't defined any explicit constraints? If Auto Layout is enabled, any changes you make to the frame will be overwritten by Auto Layout.

Comment: Auto Layout is enabled but dont have any explicit constraints.

Comment: @Anil : did you get solution for this issue? I am facing same issue now . would you plase post the answer .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue when changing between Portrait and Landscape orientation. 
Worked OK after

`self.collectionView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | 
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;`

Comment: Works even after iOS 8

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, so I've changed the frame in viewDidLayoutSubviews method. Hope this helps!